# How to identify deleted vs. undeleted ids in a trigger

Tags: trigger, triggercontext, delete

I am trying to calculate sums of child records in a master-detail rel. in a trigger and recalculate if child records are inserted, updated, or deleted. We decided not to use a formula to avoid excessive recalculating on api calls. The issue is that it's recalculating fine on inserts and updates, but on deletes, it recalculates including the existing values, but it's successfully running the deletes.

```
trigger MulitTechUpdates on Workspace_Technology__c (after insert, after update, after delete) {

    //Get ids of the children that were inserted, updated or deleted
    Set<Id> wtIds = trigger.isDelete ? trigger.oldMap.keySet() : trigger.newMap.keySet();        

    //Get the parent records of affected child records from above
    List<Workspace__c> workspaces = [
            SELECT Id, Product__c, Service__c, (SELECT Id, BE_Type__c, Expected_000__c FROM Workspace_Technologies__r) 
            FROM AT_Workspace__c
            WHERE Id IN (SELECT workspace__c FROM Workspace_Technology__c WHERE Id IN :wtIds)];

    //For all of the parent records with new/updated/removed children, calculate the sum of the dollar amount on each child
    for (Workspace__c w : workspaces) {  

        //Reset both sums to zero
        w.Product__c = 0.0;
        w.Service__c = 0.0;

        //Based on whether the child affects the product or service dollar amount, add it to the sum as long as it still exists and was not deleted
        for(Workspace_Technology__c wt : w.Workspace_Technologies__r) {
            if(!trigger.isDelete || !wtIds.contains(wt.Id)) {
                if(wt.BE_Type__c == 'Product')
                    w.Product__c += wt.Expected_000__c;
                if(wt.BE_Type__c == 'Service')
                    w.Service__c += wt.Expected_000__c;
            }
        }        
    }        
    upsert workspaces;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the Salesforce [Order of Execution](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_triggers_order_of_execution.htm), committing DML operations is one of the last things that takes place in a trigger. What that means is that the records in your delete trigger set are still in your SOQL. Consider collecting all of the parent ids and then performing your SOQL of the children based on those parent ids, purposefully excluding the records in the delete trigger set.

Alternatively, you can remove the records you queried that are in the delete set, as long as your deleted records are kept track separately.

```
if (trigger.isDelete) Map<id, Workspace_Technology__c deletedMap = Trigger.oldMap;
```

Then in your last for loop, you can add this if statement:

```
if (!deletedMap.containsKey(wt.id)) {
    //perform your rollup addition
}
```

EDIT: you could also just change the last line of your if statement to:

```
if (!Trigger.isDelete || (Trigger.isDelete && !wtIds.contains(wt.Id)))
```

Comment: So that's what I'm trying to do with the `List<Workspace__c> workspaces`. That gets the ids of the parent records, and then I do the sums based on all of their children to include existing child records. I (attempt to) exclude the deleted ones in this line `(!trigger.isDelete || !wtIds.contains(wt.Id))`, but they are still included. Is that what you were referring to?

Comment: You almost have it excluding correctly, but not quite. This would also work: if (!Trigger.isDelete || (Trigger.isDelete && !wtIds.contains(wt.Id))) I'll edit my answer to include this

Comment: hm just dropped that in and it still didn't work. The recalculation didn't happen - still includes the deleted child.

Comment: So I just figured out the answer - in my existing code, I changed it to "before delete" and it worked?